# Express OPTIONS handler never gets a chance to run

Tags: javascript, express, http-options-method

I have some express routers specified like so:

```
const getFooRouter = Router().get('/foo', (_, res) => {
  res.json({ method: 'get', path: 'foo' })
})
const putFooRouter = Router().put('/foo', (_, res) => {
  res.json({ method: 'put', path: 'foo' })
})
const postBarRouter = Router().post('/bar', (_, res) => {
  res.json({ method: 'post', path: 'bar' })
})
```

Then I compose these into a single router representing the whole app logic

```
const mainRouter = Router().use(getFooRouter, putFooRouter, postBarRouter)
```

Finally I create an app, and run it like this:

```
const expressApp = express()
expressApp.use(mainRouter)
expressApp.listen(3333)
```

What I'm trying to do next, is add another `Router` that looks like this, to handle CORS, specific for each path:

```
const corsRouter = Router()
  .options('/foo', (_, res) => {
    res.json({ method: 'options', path: 'foo' })
  })
  .options('/bar', (_, res) => {
    res.json({ method: 'options', path: 'bar' })
  })
```

Then add this after my main router, so my app looks like this:

```
const expressApp = express()
expressApp.use(mainRouter)
expressApp.use(corsRouter)
expressApp.listen(3333)
```

The issue is, that none of the handlers get hit in my CORS router. Instead, when I hit for example `OPTIONS http://localhost:3333/foo` I'm getting something, what I assume express is doing on its own, which is a peculiar response with this body:

```
GET,HEAD
```

If I remove `mainRouter`, and my setup looks like this:

```
const expressApp = express()
expressApp.use(corsRouter)
expressApp.listen(3333)
```

The requests are going through fine to `corsRouter`. I'm using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) for testing if it matter.

**Question**: What am I doing wrong in terms of **structuring** these routers?

**NOTE**:

- Pease don't suggest ready-made CORS middlewares or similar stuff like that, I'm specifically interested why my `corsRouter` is not getting hit in this setup, and what do I need to do to correct this.
- The reason it's structured like this, because this is generated from an OpenAPI document, and the structure lends itself nicely.

Comment: @NeNaD for now I'm testing from a tool called Insomnia (similar to Postman). It does send OPTIONS requests, as if I remove `expressApp.use(mainRouter)`, the request is going through to `corsRouter`. I'll update the question to be more specific.

Comment: @robertklep I updated the question, this statement doesn't seem to be accurate, as I can attach the options handlers on the Router, and it works fine without `mainRouter` being used.

Comment: @BalázsÉdes yeah you're right, I'm writing up an answer on why I think this happens.

Comment: @robertklep thank you, any help is appreciated, I'm losing my remaining hair from this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a router instance, when hit with an `OPTIONS` request, will, if none of its routes matches the request *but it has routes for other methods that match the same path*, run a default `OPTIONS` handler which returns the response you see (`GET,HEAD`).

In your case the `mainRouter` is receiving requests first and it will run the aforementioned default handler.

If you switch around the order in which you mount the routers, it works as expected:

```
expressApp.use(corsRouter)
expressApp.use(mainRouter)
```

You can philosophise about whether this is a bug or not. My guess is that due to Express internals, it can't keep track if a (sub-)router has handled the `OPTIONS` response, so it will basically get default-handled by the first router that "finishes".

An alternative way of fixing this is to declare the `OPTIONS` handler on the router that handles the "regular" request.

Comment: thank you, switching the routers definitely made it work. Do you know if this behaviour is documented anywhere?

Comment: @BalázsÉdes not sure if you saw my edit already, it's even more subtle than I initially thought. I haven't found anything in the documentation about this, I dove into the source :D

Comment: Thank you for going out of your way to check this! These implicit opinionated behaviours are crazy in express... :D